# How to go deeper on parsing xml file using libxml2

Tags: c, xml, parsing, libxml2

I'm having a problem with going deeper on parsing an xml file. To keep it simple, let's assume I have this xml file structure, provided in xmlsoft.org:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<story>
  <storyinfo>
    <author>John Fleck</author>
    <datewritten>June 2, 2002</datewritten>
    <keyword>example keyword</keyword>
  </storyinfo>
  <body>
    <headline>This is the headline</headline>
    <para>This is the body text.</para>
  </body>
</story>
```

In order to retrieve each keyword from xml's alike files, developers purpose this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

void
parseStory (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *key;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"keyword"))) {
            key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            printf("keyword: %s\n", key);
            xmlFree(key);
        }
    cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}

static void
parseDoc(char *docname) {

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr cur;

    doc = xmlParseFile(docname);

    if (doc == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Document not parsed successfully. \n");
        return;
    }

    cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    if (cur == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"empty document\n");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        return;
    }

    if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "story")) {
        fprintf(stderr,"document of the wrong type, root node != story");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        return;
    }

    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"storyinfo"))){
            parseStory (doc, cur);
        }

    cur = cur->next;
    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *docname;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s docname\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }

    docname = argv[1];
    parseDoc (docname);

    return (1);
}
```

My doubt is: if, for instance, `<storyinfo>` had another attribute like

```
<storyinfo>
...
    <rev>
        <id> 26546 </id>  
    </rev>
</storyinfo>
```

How could I access / printf (e.g.) `<id>` from `<rev>` ? Bottom line, once again, how could I go deeper and deeper to get what I want? For the above example, I tried, without success:

**add this on parseDoc function before xmlFreeDoc(doc) line**

```
cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"rev"))){
            parseRev (doc, cur);
        }

    cur = cur->next;
    }
```

**create a new function, parseRev(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur):**

```
void
parseRev (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *key;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"id"))) {
            key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            printf("id: %s\n", key);
            xmlFree(key);
        }
    cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Simply call `parseRev` from `parseStory` with the `storyinfo` node.

Answer (score 0):

The important detail that seems to be missing: when you iterate every child by doing following cur->next, it only uses the IMMEDIATE children.  Iterating on the children `story` will give you `storyinfo` and `storybody`, and nothing else.

> add this on parseDoc function before xmlFreeDoc(doc) line

You don't want to do that in parseDoc, because `rev` lives inside a `storyinfo`.  Add this check to when you're iterating over the children of `storyinfo` and it should work.